# javascript function logging before finishing work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

export default async function htmlToImg(id) {
  applyShadow(false);
  return await html2canvas(document.getElementById(id), {
      scale: 1
    })
    .then(canvas => {
      applyShadow(true);
      let img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
      console.log(img)
      return img
    });
}
```

Here i shared my code.

I am trying to convert some html nodes to canvas then converting it to i**mage url.**
But, it is working but, it is giving different part of complete image sometimes **50% and sometimes 70%** of the **image**.
The html is long so, i think it is printing before it is done converting **html nodes to canvas** or **canvas.toDataURL('image/png').**

The function is **async** function so it is logging before it is done converting complete html.
Is there any way to solve it ?

Please have a look

Comment: @palaѕн Probably best not to edit a code block into a runnable snippet unless the snippet can actually be run, else it's just noise

Comment: `return await` does not make your function `htmlToImg` synchronous. When hitting `await` your function stops execution, returns a promise, and only resumes execution when promise resolves.
"The function is async function so it is logging before..." can you specify what function and what logging you are referring to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use `await`, the operation on which you are awaiting should be a promise returning function. So, even though you have put await, code is still working asynchronously. You need to return promise in await as below :

```
async function htmlToImg(id) {
    applyShadow(false);
    myImg = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById(id), {
            scale: 1
        }).then(canvas => {
            applyShadow(true);
            let img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
            console.log(img)
            resolve(img)
        });
    })
    return myImg
}
```

I hope this resolves your issue. Please let me know if you still facing any issue, I will see if I can help you more.

Comment: Hi @vipul thanks for answer . But, where i will put export default

Comment: Because i am using this function as utils inside react

Comment: I am not used to react but you can just add `export default` in front of async as you have code in your question or you can add at the end of js file as `export default htmlToImg`

Answer (score 1):

Promise : htmlToImg

```
export default = (id) =>  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById(id), {
            scale: 1
        }).then(canvas => {
            let img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
            resolve(img,null)
        }).catch(err=>reject(null,err);
})
```

Use of your promise

```
import htmlToImg from 'your htmlToImg path';

htmlToImg(pass_your_id)
.then( ( image , err ) => { 
 if(err) { console.log(err) } 
 console.log('my image',image)
})
```